# dlvr.it RSS feed posts no youtube thumbnail picture on pages wall

Tags: rss, thumbnails, feed, facebook-page

Currently I have RSS set up to post all new articles from my CMS (IP.Content) to my facebook page. Most of these posts consist of an embedded youtube video. When the RSS pulls the feed from the articles no image thumbnail or video thumbnail is getting posted.

Here is how it posts to my facebook:
[image]

Here's an example feed used:

[Feed 1](http://forum.liftersloot.com/rss/ccs/1c11-news/)

[Feed 2](http://forum.liftersloot.com/index.php?/rss/ccs/1c11-News/)

I have tested the feed in an RSS reader and the videos show up.

Here is a facebook page that uses dlvr.it and the youtube thumbnail works, which is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I have tried dlvr.it, twitterfeed, and graffitti RSS. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will help but worth a try!

Click edit on your facebook destination in dlvr.it, click post content tab and make sure post style = shared link and thumbnail style = auto-detect by facebook.

It worked for me!

Comment: Thanks Tom. These settings are enabled but still no luck. Thanks for the suggestion.